# Does reset primary keys with DBCC CHECKIDENT safe for rows with bigger Id

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, primary-key, dbcc

I have a table with primary integer key value and its auto increment one by one , the values inside were going fine until 116, suddenly after a moment it continues from 10085 value ..

I don't know why but maybe I did a shrink database. But anyway I know about DBCC CHECKIDENT command.

My question is,if I run `DBCC CHECKIDENT (mytable, RESEED, 116)` , does it harm my rows which have Id from 100085 in the future? 
I mean when one day my rows reach 100084, will sql server jump from other Ids or it will throw exception to for inserting duplicate Id?

Answer (score 2):

it is not recommended to use the following command

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (mytable, RESEED, 116)
```

because it will throw exception when your rows reaches 100084

For more info read the Following [Topic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx#Exceptions) . it says that it is recommended that All rows are deleted from the table. if you want to user     DBCC CHECKIDENT for reseeding table

Answer (score 2):

**Don't do this**

It will throw a duplicate key exception once the identity column comes up to 100084.

It doesn't magically skip previously generated values to avoid clashes. You can easily see this from the below

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
  (
     x INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
     Y INT
  )

INSERT INTO mytable
            (Y)
SELECT TOP (200) number
FROM   master..spt_values

DELETE FROM mytable
WHERE  x BETWEEN 1 AND 150;

DBCC CHECKIDENT (mytable, RESEED, 1)

/*Works OK*/
INSERT INTO mytable
            (Y)
SELECT TOP (149) number
FROM   master..spt_values

/*Error*/
INSERT INTO mytable
            (Y)
SELECT TOP (10) number
FROM   master..spt_values
```

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 25 Violation of PRIMARY KEY
>   constraint 'PK__mytable__3BD019E5518439DD'.  Cannot insert duplicate
>   key in object 'dbo.mytable'. The duplicate key value is (151). The
>   statement has been terminated.